# bootstrap fluid and static container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to combine fluid containers with fixed containers in a single page bootstrap layout.

What I want is (for example), to have a big image as a hero unit (but not with hero-unit) 100% width/height of the viewport, or a 3 column images divided by that 100%, but in other occasions (inside the same page) it will have the max 1200px container along with the grid elements of bootstrap. I plan to combine it with this http://untame.net/2013/01/how-to-design-a-single-page-scrolling-site-with-twitter-bootstrap/ to make a vertical scrolling single page site.

Is it achievable? Or I should go on a custom layout for all the "sections" of my single page and apply media queries?

I would have tried the 3 column images with the normal `.span4` and `row-fluid` but it adds gutter that I don't want. When I try to remove the gutter, the spans get shorter.

I will try to update my question soon with a working example of what I would try to do, and where I am at the moment.

*** UPDATE ***

here is a full page result of the thing I have done so far 
http://jsfiddle.net/ditikos/ejMAQ/4/embedded/result/

now `.block` refers to the javascript class that will generate the pages so that they would be minimum of the viewport height (in the second situation of the `.thumbnail`, it can get up to 2x the viewport height because there could also be a set of 6 thumbnails in one page)

- How can I put the three columns `.block` in a way that when I get to the phone view it would stack like the normal grid?
- I am actually trying to make a three column content carousel with the `.aThird` slices. Is it possible with a grid layout?

Comment: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html  Just read this website carefully.  It teaches you how to do pretty much everything.  If you still have questions, come back and ask with some concrete code examples.

Comment: I will post code soon, I am on a phone right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read Bootstrap's website you would find:

- Basic fluid grid HTML**
- "Make any row "fluid" by changing .row to .row-fluid. The column classes stay the exact same, making it easy to flip between fixed and fluid grids."

**Edit**: This answer is not valid for bootstrap 3

Comment: That feature seems to be gone with bootstrap 3.

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah You haven't visited the site in a bit. Bootstrap 3 is now current.
http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2013/08/19/bootstrap-3-released/