# Bootstrap fluid-container within non-fluid container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fluid-layout

Since this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14839128/bootstrap-fluid-and-static-container) is outdated my question is how do I create a `fluid row` within non-fluid container.

I want to have a non-fluid container as my default layout, however the map I am placing, i need it to be full-width non-fluid.

here is my html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div id="map-canvas" class="container-fluid"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`row-fluid` is not working with bootstrap 3, setting `width: 100%;` only takes width of its parent (non-fluid container).

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m1L6pfwm/), Please increase output window width so you can see the difference.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just a quick question to clarify; do you mean 'fluid'?

Comment: Oops yes, sorry for typo, a consistent typo...

Comment: @odedta http://jsfiddle.net/m1L6pfwm/ attached...

Comment: This is basically going to break the Bootstrap markup and reasoning... the whole post in having a parent that is non fluid is just that and you're trying to break it... if you really need to do that just use `position:fixed;width: 100% !important;`. Seriously now, you're trying to create bad markup! use good HTML markup to achieve what you like, if you can't change the HTML directly use jQuery for that.

Comment: Thanks well do that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that a completely understand your question, but can't you just use Bootstrap's `container-fluid` to contain the map `row`?

http://bootply.com/KP9j6dKCES

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row" style="height:100px; background: #f00;">
        this should take 100% width
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I wanted to have a single container and not a mixture otherwise what you have suggested is achieves my result.

Answer (score 5):

Try following code. You can make a 100% width container inside fixed layout.

http://jsfiddle.net/m1L6pfwm/2/

HTML

```
 <div class="row row-full"> content... </>
```

CSS

```
.row-full{
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: -50vw;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  left: 50%;
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly as i wanted but I don't understand why put `margin-left` and `left` properties? and more importantly why it won't work without these two properties? A bit explanation would be nice. Thanks.

Comment: We need both properties in order to get it center aligned. following is the visual explanation. 

http://postimg.org/image/dry5m6fzt/

Answer (score 0):

Either use apropriate layout
or get same effect using following

```
<div class="row-fluid" style="position:absolute;z-index:5">
        <div id="map-canvas" class="container-fluid"></div>
</div>

<div class="container" style="z-index:0">
    <--fluid with respect to first static/relative parent-->
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div id="map-canvas" class="container-fluid"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can play same effect using Z-index but not with it's grand parent

Comment: you are right that's what i want. solution is i have to different containers but i want a more appropriate solution then dividing my layout into multiple  containers